# VeraCrypt OS X asks for administrator privileges

Tags: veracrypt

I am using a non-admin user. As the title suggests my VeraCrypt on OS X asks for administrator privileges. After i enter the password of the administrator account, i get the following error: "Failed to obtain administrator privileges".

If i try it on the administrator account, everything works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you running VeraCrypt? How'd you install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your non-admin user and the veracrypt command in the sudoers file.
Login as the admin user and run in the terminal:

```
sudo visudo
```

The 'visudo' command is the recommended way to edit the /etc/sudoers file.
You need to add a line similar to this:

```
your-non-admin-username ALL = (ALL) /Applications/VeraCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/VeraCrypt
```

Next time when VeraCrypt asks you for the password you have to provide the non-admin user's password, not the administrator's password.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.

I added a group and configured it to require no password, which makes it much easier for the colleagues using it.

`%group-without-domain ALL=NOPASSWD: /Applications/VeraCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/VeraCrypt`